# Handling deployment dependency across different solution files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, biztalk

I have multiple **BizTalk** solution files containing multiple projects. These solution files have **deployment dependency**, i.e. before deploying one solution i need to deployed the solution on which it is dependent first.

How can i handle this dependency across different solution files?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you must undeploy and redeploy in the order of the dependency chain.

Unfortunately, there is no way around this as it is enforced by the deployment manager.

There are different approaches to alliviating this.  My typical plan is to design the solutions around deployment packages, even if that means having essentially duplicate schemas.  The only notible extra step is having to explicity set the Doc Spec on the XmlDisassemblers.

Comment: +1 re (un)deployment w.r.t. dependency chain. More info on handling duplicate [`xmlns#root` schema issues here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600665/deploying-multiple-similar-schemas-in-biztalk)